# Android dialogs, simple architectural question

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog

According to your experience, would you handle dialogs on an `Activity` level, or would let the `Fragment` itself take care of them.

Let me give you a more concrete example. Say you have a fragment that asks the user for a username and password to log in into your app. would you create an interface with the following methods

> **onSuccessfulLogIn()**  // takes the user to another activity
>
> **onInvalidCredentials()** // shows a toast reading "invalid credentials"
>
> **onNoInternetError()** // shows a toast reading "Make sure you're
>   connected to the internet. turn on wifi".
>
> **onNetworkError()** // shows a toast reading "sorry, there was a problem
>   with the server, try again"
>
> **showWaitingProgressDialog()** shows a progress dialog.

or would you just show those toast / dialogs inside the fragment.

Both ways work just fine. I'm just curious about which one is better.

Basically, I'm asking:
**Dummy UI fragments and a monolithic activity** vs **Modular, encapsulated fragments with activities that just handle interactions between them.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better keep it inside the fragment if not necessary. If u have to pass some data in the methods, then only u should go with interfaces. Moreover, I will recommend using getTargetFragment and setTargetFragment stuff to pass data.

Here is good example for that : https://github.com/alexfu/TargetFragmentExample